# $\mathbb{F}_{4} =\mathbb{F}_{2}[x] / (x^2 + x + 1)\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$\mathbb{F}_{4} =\mathbb{F}_{2}[x] / (x^2 + x + 1)\mathbb{F}_{2}[x]$ if $\mathbb{F}$ is the notation for fields. Now, one way to represent $\mathbb{F}_{4}$ is the following:

$\mathbb{F}_{4} = \{0, 1, x, x+1\}$ assuming $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$. Then, I was told that in this case, $x$ + $(x+1) = 1.$ You can even make a four by four addition table and multiplication table to find all the possible values. I am a little unsure where $x$ + $(x+1) = 1$ though. Where does $x^2 + x + 1$ even come into play? If I was looking at $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ could I represent it as $\{0, x, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5, x+6, x+7\}$ then?

Comment: what all possibilities do you see for $x+(x+1)$ after thanking closure of field under addition??? can you exclude at least one possibilities in $\{0, 1, x, x+1\}$.....

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can $x+(x+1)=x$???? can $x+(x+1)=x+1$???

Comment: This is where I was a little unsure. Intuitively, the first one works if $x = -1$ however I know that this digressing from abstract algebra. The point I am making with this example is that I do not see why $x + (x + 1) = 1$ literally. I was trying to think of it as modular arithmetic but it quickly got ruled out. Another example I see on the table I have is that $x + x$ is zero.

Comment: See, if you have $x+(x+1)=x$ then $x=-1$ but this does not satisfy $x^2+x+1=0$.. Thus, $x+(x+1)\neq x$.... Now, Suppose $x+(x+1)=x+1$ then, we would have $x=0$ which can be seen to be absurd after thanking "$x^2+x+1=0$".. Is this clear now??

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$, $2=0$.

$\mathbb{F}_9$ has characteristic $3$, and so has nothing to do with $\mathbb{F}_2$. However, it is a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$, so if $\alpha$ is any element of $\mathbb{F}_9$ other than $0,1,2$, then every element of $\mathbb{F}_9$ can be uniquely expressed in the form $a + b \alpha$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_3$.

Answer (score 0):

To generate the polynomial ring, you have to assume distributivity of multiplication over addition and associativity of addition (and multiplication).

$x+x=(1+1)x=0.$

$x+(x+1)=(x+x)+1.$

By quotienting by $(x^2+x+1),$ you're saying $x^2+x+1 \equiv 0.$ This equivalence relation is a congruence relation, so together with the other axioms it induces the values of the rest of the table from the normal multiplication and addition of the polynomials - the products will be reduced modulo $x^2+x+1$.

As for $\mathbb{F}_9$, there is no sum of $1$ which is equal to $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$. So, for all elements of a quotient to be of the form $x+c$, $c$ a sum of $1$, your ideal has to contain some element of the form $x-(1+1+...)$. Furthermore, you have to define ${3, 4, 5, 6, 7}$, because those are not elements of $\mathbb{F}_3$ already.